# How to resolve duplicate stock movement and order notifications in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have been troubleshooting this issue for the last few weeks and have not been able to resolve.

We are experiencing the following (intermittently) when an order is placed by a customer.

- Stock movement is duplicated
- Order notes are duplicated
- Email notifications are duplicated (to all parties)
- Backorders are created (if the stock on hand is not sufficient to handle the duplicate qty). Example: initial inventory = 1 unit. 1 unit is purchased but the stock movement is duplicated which takes inventory to -1 causing a backorder, despite back orders being set to "do not allow".

Stack

- Osmosis theme (+ child theme) - v4.3.6 (just updated to latest version)
- Woocommerce v6.4.1
- WordPress v5.9.3
- PHP v7.4.28
- Flywheel/5.1.0, nginx

The issue appears to have started a couple of weeks prior to a migration to a new host. A review of orders prior to the migration showed that order notes were already duplicating. After the move to the new host, it seems the stock movement started to duplicate (as well as order notification emails).

I reached out to Flywheel, they took a look but could not see anything suspicious-looking in the logs other than some fatal errors in the theme. I updated the theme. This resolved the fatal errors but not the order issue. Flywheel also adjusted the PHP memory, but no dice on the order issues. They have not provided much more help.

I updated a bunch of plugins at the same time as I migrated the site to Flywheel, so a possible conflict with a plugin may exist.

I tested in a staging environment with themes and plugins disabled but can not replicate.

It's hard to tell which plugin/theme might be causing a conflict on the staging site, as the issue is intermittent, so it's hard to narrow down which plugin, or if it is even a conflict. We also don't have the volume of orders going through the staging site, so hard to figure out. We would need to process several test orders over the course of a day. Which I guess we can do.

I did some googling and saw a bunch of posts on a similar issue relating to the payment gateway, and a possible conflict between using the hosted payment page or merchant payment page. I reached out to the developer (Windcave / Payment Express). They were not aware of any conflicts but sent me an older version of the plugin so I could roll it back. No dice. I also had the client reach out to Windcave directly to check their account was configured correctly and all appears to be as it should.

I've checked all Woocommerce settings, run all updates on plugins, reviewed the woocommerce status report, and checked logs.

I'm left with placing a bunch of test orders in the staging site over a few days until I can narrow down a possible plugin conflict, but wanted to fire this query through here first to see if anyone had come across something simiar and can help me resolve.

Would greatly appreciate some help.

Thanks
Josh

Answer (score 0):

I think it can relate some of the WordPress hooks that are used for checkout page. You can check in this link "https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-checkout-page/" for the hooks that can possible used on checkout page (or) before order create hooks. Try to compare these hooks names and if you used these hooks in child theme > functions.php or plugins. Some of hooks can trigger 2 or 3 times so it can possible be the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look and come back here with what I find. Cheers.